# Wordpress shortcode function returns only the title

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

my problem is that: Trying to retrieve the_content with a simple shortcode function, it retrieves only the title.
Even applying another filters the result is always the same.

- The content is from a page.
- The function is declared in the functions.php theme file.
- Using the post (page) id.

  ```
      function shtcode_Func( $atts = array() ) {

    // set up default parameters
     extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'id' => '5'
     ), $atts));

     $my_postid = $atts;//This is page id or post id
     $content_post = get_post($my_postid);
     $content = $content_post->post_content;
     $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
     $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

     return $content;
  }

  add_shortcode('shortcodePage', 'shtcode_Func');
  ```

Calling from widget with `[shortcodePage id=POST_ID] (int)`

Result: Prints only the title.
I tried to change the filter with 'the_post_thumbnail' and retrieved the title again.

I'm desperated :(

Thanks!!

Comment: Might not _be_ the filters … have you verified that `$content` actually contained what you expected it to?

Comment: Yes I did. Page has some text and a block with a video. So there are a title, and two blocks, a paragraph and a video

Comment: Seen too if there is something hidden in the DOM... Nothing. Only a tiny text with the title is printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things incorrect with your shortcode function, but the main things:

1. You are using `extract` but not using anything from `extract`
2. `$atts` is an array, not just the `id`.
3. You are using `apply_filters('the_content')`. This essentially overwrites WPs built in apply_filter. You want to use `add_filter`, but as you can see that won't be necessary.

Here is the shortcode trimmed down with what you are trying to do:

```
function shtcode_Func( $atts ) {

    // set up default parameters. No need to use extract here.
    $a = shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => ''
    ), $atts);

    // Use get_the_content, and pass the actual ID
    $content = get_the_content('','', $a['id'] );
    // This is the same
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    // Return the content.
    return $content;
}

add_shortcode('shortcodePage', 'shtcode_Func');
```

Comment: I love you!! 
Thanks! For the solutions and the explanation.

I Just can sleep thank to you

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use like this:
function shtcode_Func( $atts = array() ) {

    // set up default parameters
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => '5'
    ), $atts));

    $content_post = get_post( $atts['id'] );
    ob_start();
    $content = $content_post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
    echo $content;
    $str = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    return $str;
}

add_shortcode('shortcodePage', 'shtcode_Func');
```